# Increase tapping area for question opening

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

Currently in mobile web to open a question you need to tap on the question's title only.

> [image: qlist]

Is it possible to use whole question rectangle (i.e. background) for this purpose? It could be much easier to use in mobile devices.

Such behavior is already used in iOS app:

> [image: ios]